# How do I use Process.Start with a path which is in a label?

Tags: c#

I am using

```
Process.Start(@"lbl_path.Text");
```

With and without quotes, but, it doesn't seem to work. I added `using System.Diagnostics;`

The text contained in `lbl_Path` will be in constant change, that is why I'm not typing the path in after the '@'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passes a constant string:

```
Process.Start(@"lbl_path.Text");
```

This passes the Text property of the lbl_path Label:

```
Process.Start(lbl_path.Text);
```

This escapes the \ characters from the Text of the Label and passes it:

```
Process.Start(lbl_path.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
// or
Process.Start(lbl_path.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Comment: Really helped me mate
    `Process.Start(lbl_path.Text);`
did it for me

but what is the difference of

    `Process.Start(lbl_path.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    // or
    Process.Start(lbl_path.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\");`
from
    `Process.Start(lbl_path.Text)`

Comment: @Doug_MT the first replaces the \ characters from the path and makes them \\, while the second doesn't. That's called escape characters, and might be the solution when you get an invalid path error.

Answer (score 0):

This will more appropriate way to escape + use the string from the label.

```
Process.Start(lbl_path.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\"));
```